# Sort a list based on two conditions

Tags: java, android, sorting

So, I don't know if there is an elegant solution to this but here goes. I want to sort a list but the list contains three types of items. What i want is for type A to be on top sorted alphabetically, type B & C to be on the bottom and sorted alphabetically (type B & C will be combined).

Here is my code:

```
public int compareTo(Friendship another) {
    if(this.getType().equals(TypeA) &&
            another.getType().equals(TypeA)){ //if they are both type A, just sort based on user name

        return this.getUsername().compareTo(
                another.getUsername());
    }
    else if(this.getType.equals(TypeA)){ 
        return -1;
    }
    else if(another.getType().equals(TypeA)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{ //this will be hit if they are either Type B or C, then just sort based on username
        return this.getUsername().compareTo(
                another.getUsername());
    }
}
```

EDIT: sorry, I should have explained this a lot better. The problem is that the above code isn't working. From what I am seeing, the list doesn't seem to be properly ordered. 

<strike>The TypeA list is for some reason ordered opposite of what I want( Z -> A). And the TypeB & C list is only half sorted. So I am assuming that there is a bug in my code. Let me know if you need more info</strike>.

EDIT2: Did some more tests on samples and it looks like the strings aren't being sorted at all. I did both

```
this.getUsername().compareTo(
            another.getUsername());
```

and

```
another.getUsername().compareTo(
            this.getUsername());
```

EDIT 3: you guys were right. there was a mistake elsewhere in my code (that was unrelated). Sorry... also don't really know what to do in this case. Who do I give the right answer to?

Comment: Your alphabetical sorting will not work the way that you have specified.

String.compareTo(String) uses lexicographical ordering. You may need to add some consideration for case-sensitivity.

Sorry if that makes it slightly less elegant to look at.

Comment: @StephenSouness I don't think it should matter that much. it should just sort it exactly how strings are normally sorted

Comment: Ok.  It's difficult to tell without more context, but if you're happy for Zebra to show before aardvark (for example) then that's your decision.

Comment: I'd say toss a coin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i be you, i won't change structure, but only optimize this little bit

```
public int compareTo(Friendship another) {


       if(!this.getType().equals(another.getType()){
        //if type are not equal, so we might have at most one A

          if(this.getType.equals(TypeA)){ //on left side
             return -1;
          }

          if(another.getType().equals(TypeA)){ //or, on rightside
            return 1;
          }
        }
          //or we have on both sides or neither side
            return this.getUsername().compareTo(
                    another.getUsername());
        }
```

Comment: @sree if you want revenrse order do `another.getUsername().compareTo( this.getUsername())` can you also provide some sample data

Comment: I did what you suggested and gathered more data. Please see my edit, it seems like the strings are not being sorted at all

Comment: @Sree can you provide some input and output sample, because for me it is working fine http://ideone.com/5BsqqJ

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please see the edit, it was a mistake on my end but everyone's logic was right. What do I do in this case, in terms of putting the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar solution in the same situation, and I think it is good.

But code can be shorter:

```
public int compareTo(Friendship another) {
    boolean thisOnTop = getType().equals(TypeA);
    boolean anotherOnTop = another.getType().equals(TypeA);
    if (thisOnTop != anotherOnTop) {
        return thisOnTop ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
        return this.getUsername().compareTo(another.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Comment: I like how simple your code is. But please see my edit. I am sorry I should have explained myself better. Did you also have to sort a list with two different conditions in your program?

Comment: @Sree yes, and it works. Probably, `getType().equals(TypeA)` doesn't work as you expected. Also is `getUsername()` a regular string (or complex object that implements Comparable)?

Comment: TypeA is just an enum, and username is just a string

Comment: Please see my edit, it looks like the strings are not being sorted at all

Comment: @Sree are you sorting it with `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: yes i am, i assume that is the right way to do it, right?

Comment: @Sree yes, sure. This method definitely should sort simple strings properly. Is it possible that problem somewhere else in your program?

Comment: @Sree by the way you can compare enum constants with `==`

Comment: Guys, thanks for the help. Please see the edit, it was a mistake on my end but everyone's logic was right. What do I do in this case, in terms of putting the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to implement your compareTo in the 3 classes with that logic you said. Something like this:

```
// TypeA.class
// TypeA class will have priority over the other two, so just sort by whatever you want
public int compareTo(AnotherType anotherType) {
    if (this.equals(anotherType)) // TypeA vs TypeA - alphabetically
        return this.getUsername().compareTo(anotherType.getUsername());
    else // otherwise typeA is greater
        return 1; // 1 means greater than
}

// TypeB.class
public int compareTo(AnotherType anotherType) {
    if (this.equals(anotherType)) // both typeB, sort alphabetically
        return this.getUsername().compareTo(anotherType.getUsername());
    else
        if(this.equals(typeC)) // TypeB vs TypeC, alphabetically
            return this.getUsername().compareTo(typeC.getUsername());
        else // TypeB vs TypeA
            return -1; // -1 means lesser than
}

//TypeC.class
public int compareTo(AnotherType anotherType) {
    if (this.equals(anotherType)) // TypeC vs TypeC - alphabetically
        return this.getUsername().compareTo(anotherType.getUsername());
    else
    if(this.equals(typeB)) // TypeC vs TypeB - alphabetically
        return this.getUsername().compareTo(typeB.getUsername());
    else
        return -1; // -1 means lesser than
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I think the base logic won't change between your code and mine would it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an elegant way to solve this, and it does not involve ugly compareTo trainwrecks.

1. Pass through your list and make 2 `SortedSet`, one for `A` and one for `B + C`. Add your Friendships based on their Type.
2. Make a new list and use `Collections.addAll()` method to appent to the  list the 2 arrays you can get from the 2 `SortedSet`, first the one for `A`, then the one for `B+C`.

Since `SortedSet` will keep the contents in natural order, which is lexicographical for strings, your final list will have Type `A` first, sorted lexicographically, `B and C` after, also sorted lexicographically.

Comment: i thought of this but was hoping to not do this since it seemed inelegant. do you not think so?

Comment: Compared to all these super ugly comparators, this seems fairly clean to me. No if( ...) elseif (...) else {  if(....) elsif (....) else {...} } = big win.

Comment: so instead creating one single comparator for application, you will create 3 lists , really "nice and clean" way

Comment: Actually, you create 1 list and 2 sets. Sets are fast, and they will be local to the method where you actually need them sorted. Think about extending this with another type, that'll make for a nice "single" comparator with x number of branches, which, by the way, is considered a code smell.